# I have a task of running Jenkins source code on a local tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, github, jenkins

I have a task of running Jenkins source code on a local tomcat server

The problem I’m facing is am not able to customize the source code because it's a war file(collection of classes - executable files)

I have downloaded a Source code from github.

Kindly suggest any solution so that it will  be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply deploy the jenkins.war file to Tomcat like you would any other war file.